# SystemVerilog Convert `define Concatenated String Evaluated into Int Definition

Tags: concatenation, c-preprocessor, system-verilog, atoi

I have a long list `defines defining with numerous properties for these registers.  I'd like to have a function that takes the string of the register name and concatenates the big`define name and evaluates the `define int value upon process.

A simple function called liked the following:

PrintRegInfor(REGA);

Here's the class code that doesnt work:

```
`define CHIP_REGA_ADDR   16'h0000
`define CHIP_REGA_RESET_VAL   0
`define CHIP_REGB_ADDR   16'h0100
`define CHIP_REGB_RESET_VAL   1

.
.
`define CHIP_REGZ_ADDR       16'h1000
`define CHIP_REGZ_RESET_VAL  0

clase module;
function PrintRegInfo(string reg_name)
    string reg_reset_string;
    string reg_addr_string;
    int reg_reset_int;
    int reg_addr_int;
    reg_reset_string = {"`CHIP_",reg_name,"_RESET_VAL"};
    reg_addr_string = {"`CHIP_",reg_name,"_ADDR"};
    reg_reset_int = reg_reset_string;
    reg_add_int = reg_add_string;
    $display("Reg %s at address 0x%x has a reset value of 0x%x\n",reg_name, reg_add_int,reg_reset_int);
endfunction
endclass
```

It looks like the conversion of string to int is converting the actual string from the ascii value into int.  I'd like it to evaluate the `define of the string created.  Is this possible?

I would like to get:

Reg Rega at address 0x0000 has a reset value of 0x0

I get something like:
Reg Rega at address 0x3478 has a reset value of 0x8373

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use string variables to form identifiers in procedural code. You could create a macro to do this

```
`define PrintRegInfo(reg_name) \
  $display("Reg %s at address 0x%x has a reset value of 0x%x\n", `"reg_name`", \
 `CHIP_``reg_name``_ADDR, \
  `CHIP_``reg_name``RESET_VAL);
```

However, the argument you pass to the macro cannot be a string variable. 
You might rethink the way you organize your data by not using `define` statements and instead create a database with associative arrays.

Comment: Thanks Dave. I'm living with an existing environment. I normally use assoc arrays or even class objects. Thanks for answering.